# SingleView ImageLoader Display NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-gridview

I am new to Android development and Java in general. I realize that this question may seem quite elementary, but I am just not understanding despite looking on numerous forums, reading about the exception and debugging my activity.

I am trying to parse JSON image data into a GridView.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class JSONImageViewer extends Activity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    static String TAG_IMG = "CarImageLink";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get the view from gridview_item.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.gridview_item);

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(JSONImageViewer.this);

            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            //Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("......");


            try {
                //Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("car_images");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Retrieve JSON Object
                    map.put("CarImageLink", jsonobject.getString("CarImageLink"));

                    //Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            //Locate the Gridview in gridview_main.xml
            GridView gridview;
            gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(JSONImageViewer.this, arraylist);

            //Set the adapter to the GridView
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

            //Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public static class JSONfunctions {

        public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            JSONObject jArray = null;

            //Download JSON data from URL
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

            //Convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            try {

                jArray = new JSONObject(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            return jArray;
        }
    }

    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        ImageLoader imageLoader;
        HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
            this.context = context;
            data = arraylist;
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ImageView carimg;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);

            //Get the position
            resultp = data.get(position);
            //resultp.put(TAG_IMG,data.get(position).get("CarImageLink"));
            //resultp.put(TAG_IMG,data.get(position).get("CarImageLink))"));
            Log.v("resultp", resultp.toString());
            //Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
            carimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_img);
            //Capture position and set results to the ImageView
            //Passes images URL into ImageLoader.class
            int loader = R.drawable.temp_img;
            int stub_id = loader;
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(JSONImageViewer.TAG_IMG),stub_id, carimg);


            Log.v("resultp e1", (resultp.get(TAG_IMG).toString()));
            //Log.v("carimg", carimg.toString());
            Log.v("resultp e2", resultp.toString());


            //Capture ListView item click
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //Get the position
                    resultp = data.get(position);
                    //resultp.put(TAG_IMG,data.get(position).get("CarImageLink"));

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);

                    // Pass all data
                    intent.putExtra("CarImageLink", resultp.get(JSONImageViewer.TAG_IMG));

                    //Start SingleItemView Class
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            return itemView;
        }
    }

    public class ImageLoader {

        MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
        FileCache fileCache;
        private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
        ExecutorService executorService;

        // Handler to display images in UI thread
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        public ImageLoader(Context context){
            fileCache=new FileCache(context);
            executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        }

        int stub_id = R.drawable.temp_img;
        public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
        {
            try {

                stub_id = loader;
                imageViews.put(imageView, url);
                Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
                if(bitmap!=null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Log.v("Bitmap 3", bitmap.toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    queuePhoto(url, imageView);
                    imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
            executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
        }

        private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

            Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
            if (b != null) {
                Log.v("bitmap 4", b.toString());
                return b;
            }
            //Download Images from the Internet
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                // Log.v("Bitmap 5", bitmap.toString());
                Uri.Builder uri = Uri.parse("....").buildUpon();
                uri.appendPath(url);
                uri.build();
                Log.v("Build", uri.build().toString());
                Log.v("Uri", uri.toString());

                URL imageUrl = new URL ("http://"+ "....com" + url);
                Log.v("URL 3", imageUrl.toString());

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                os.close();
                conn.disconnect();
                bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                //Log.v("bitmap 6", bitmap.toString());
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                    memoryCache.clear();
                return null;
            }
        }

        //Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
        private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
            try {
                //Decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
                stream1.close();

                //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
                int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
                int scale = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                            || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp /= 2;
                    height_tmp /= 2;
                    scale *= 2;
                }

                //Decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
                stream2.close();
                Log.v("bitmap 7", bitmap.toString());
                return bitmap;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        //Task for the queue
        private class PhotoToLoad {

            public String url;
            public ImageView imageView;

            public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
                url = u;
                imageView = i;
            }
        }

        class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

            PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
                this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                       // return;
                    Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                    Log.v("URL 2", photoToLoad.url.toString());
                    Log.v("Bitmap  bmp", bmp.toString());
                    memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);

                    //if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                        //return;
                    //BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                    //handler.post(bd);
                    //Log.v("bd", bd.toString());

                } catch (Throwable th) {
                    th.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

       /* boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
            if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
*/
        class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
            public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
                bitmap=b;
                Log.v("bitmap b", b.toString());
                photoToLoad=p;
            }
           public void run(){
              // if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
                   //Log.v("BITMAP", bitmap.toString());
                  // return;
               //}
               Log.v("BITMAP", bitmap.toString());
                if(bitmap != null) {
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Log.v("bitmap 2", bitmap.toString());
                }
                else {
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
                }
            }
        }


        public void clearCache() {
            memoryCache.clear();
            fileCache.clear();
        }

    }
    public class MemoryCache {

        private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

        //Last argument true for LRU ordering
        private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections
                .synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10, 1.5f, true));

        //Current allocated size
        private long size = 0;

        //Max memory in bytes
        private long limit = 1000000;

        public MemoryCache() {
            //Use 25% of available heap size
            setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 4);
        }

        public void setLimit(long new_limit) {
            limit = new_limit;
        }

        public Bitmap get(String id) {
            try {
                if (!cache.containsKey(id))
                    return null;
                return cache.get(id);
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
            try {
                if (cache.containsKey(id))
                    size -= getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
                cache.put(id, bitmap);
                size += getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
                checkSize();
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void checkSize() {
            Log.i(TAG, "cache size=" + size + " length=" + cache.size());
            if (size > limit) {

                //Least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter = cache.entrySet().iterator();

                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<String, Bitmap> entry = iter.next();
                    size -= getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                    iter.remove();
                    if (size <= limit)
                        break;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size " + cache.size());
            }
        }

        public void clear() {
            try {
                cache.clear();
                size = 0;
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (bitmap == null)
                return 0;
            return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
        }
    }

    public class FileCache {

        private File cacheDir;

        public FileCache(Context context) {

            //Find the dir to save cached images
            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                cacheDir = new File(
                        android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "");
            else
                cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
            if (!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }

        public File getFile(String url) {
            String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
            //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
            File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
            return f;

        }

        public void clear() {
            File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
            if (files == null)
                return;
            for (File f : files)
                f.delete();
        }

    }
    public static class Utils {
        public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
        {
            final int buffer_size=1024;
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
                for(;;)
                {
                    int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                    if(count==-1)
                        break;
                    os.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }

    public class SingleItemView extends Activity {

        String carimg;
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //Get the view from singleitemview.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

            Intent i = getIntent();
            //Get the result of CarImageLink
            carimg = i.getStringExtra("CarImageLink");
            Log.v("carimg", i.getStringExtra("CarImageLink").toString());

            int loader = R.drawable.temp_img;
            int stub_id = loader;
            //Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
            ImageView img_car = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.car_img);
            Log.v("Imageview img_car", img_car.toString());

            //Capture position and set results to the ImageView
            //Passes carimg images URL into ImageLoader.class
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(carimg, stub_id, img_car);
        }
    }
```

griview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cars"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/car_id"
        android:text="@string/id"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/car_vin"
        android:layout_below="@id/car_id"
        android:text="@string/vin"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/model_img"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/car_id"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

singleitemview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/temp_img" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions as to how to solve these errors would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Update:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.justin.myapplication.JSONImageViewer$ImageLoader.DisplayImage(JSONImageViewer.java:290)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.justin.myapplication.JSONImageViewer$ListViewAdapter.getView(JSONImageViewer.java:229)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1341)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:341)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:417)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1229)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-30 15:30:54.609  29426-29426/com.example.justin.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
```

imageView.setImageResource(stub_id); for (JSONImageViewer.java:290)
imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(JSONImageViewer.TAG_IMG),stub_id, carimg); for (JSONImageViewer.java:229)

Comment: You can use picasso library to load images into imageView.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Hello @DeepakGoyal . I have looked into Picasso, but I want to load images into gridView and NOT imageView. Any suggestions NOT involving Picasso would be great, please. Thanks.

Comment: Your gridview must consist of grid item and that grid item contains imageview. So load the image into that imageview

Comment: @DeepakGoyal I realize this, but I would prefer to stay away from Picasso implementations as I have faced many issues with it due to the API version that I am working under. I believe: 
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(TAG_IMG), carimg); is the main issue. Any suggestions about that with the current ImageLoader that I am using would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward debugging stuff in Android.

Faced with a seemingly impenetrable Exception stack trace, the trick is scan down the list of routines looking for the first occurrence of a line of source in YOUR code. Set a breakpoint on that line, and take a look at what's actually happening. You should also look for "Caused by" inner exceptions when doing this. When there's an inner exception, you will find the problem in the stack trace for the inner except.

In your case the line of interest is the very first line in the stack trace:

```
at com.example.justin.myapplication.JSONImageViewer$ImageLoader.DisplayImage(JSONImageViewer.java:287)
```

A Null pointer exception occured in JSONImageViewer.java at line 287.

Set a breakpoint on that line in the debugger, and look to see what's happening. You can just double-click on the file and line-number in the stack trace to go straight to the source line.

I can't tell which line is line 287. But it seems to be something to do with the URL you're constructing. You should be able to figure this out pretty easily once you set a breakpoint on line 287.

Comment: Hello. Perhaps I am not fully understanding. When I debug in the way you described above, I get debugging data from a class that I have never developed. Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: If you do it right, you should end up at line 293 of the file you posted. Which is somewhere in the function "public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) ".

Comment: Great! I realized that imageViews in DisplayImage is null, but I am not understanding why even after debugging and logging. Your suggestions are greatly appreciated, sir.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue is due to the hashmap.
A hashmap is made of key and value. However, you are not saving a key to the value specified. ("resultp = data.get(position);").

Therefore, when you try to access a value of the hashmap with the key : "TAG_IMG", the app is crashing with null pointer because this will return a null value.

The correct way of fixing this issue would be :  resultp.put(TAG_IMG, data.get(position));

```
public class JSONImageViewer extends Activity {

JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

static String TAG_IMG = "CarImageLink";
GridView gridview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(JSONImageViewer.this);

        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("......");


        try {
            //Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("car_images");
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                //Retrieve JSON Object
                map.put("CarImageLink" + i,                        jsonobject.getString("CarImageLink"));

                //Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        if (arraylist != null && arraylist.size() > 0) {
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);

            //Set the adapter to the GridView
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        //Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public static class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        //Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        //Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView carimg;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);

        //Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);
        //resultp.put(TAG_IMG,data.get(position).get("CarImageLink"));
        //resultp.put(TAG_IMG,data.get(position).get("CarImageLink))"));
        Log.v("resultp", resultp.toString());
        //Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
        carimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_img);
        //Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        //Passes images URL into ImageLoader.class
        int loader = R.drawable.temp_img;
        int stub_id = loader;
        if (carimg == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A crash is going to happen due to error in xml", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        if (resultp.get(TAG_IMG) == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A crash is going to happen due to hashma error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(TAG_IMG) + position, stub_id, carimg);


        Log.v("resultp e1", (resultp.get(TAG_IMG).toString()));
        //Log.v("carimg", carimg.toString());
        Log.v("resultp e2", resultp.toString());


        //Capture ListView item click
        /*itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                //resultp.put(TAG_IMG,data.get(position).get("CarImageLink"));

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);

                // Pass all data
                intent.putExtra("CarImageLink", resultp.get(JSONImageViewer.TAG_IMG));

                //Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });*/
        return itemView;
    }
}

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    // Handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    int stub_id = R.drawable.temp_img;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView) {
        try {

            stub_id = loader;
            imageViews.put(imageView, url);
            Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Log.v("Bitmap 3", bitmap.toString());
            } else {
                queuePhoto(url, imageView);
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null) {
            Log.v("bitmap 4", b.toString());
            return b;
        }
        //Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            // Log.v("Bitmap 5", bitmap.toString());
            Uri.Builder uri = Uri.parse("....").buildUpon();
            uri.appendPath(url);
            uri.build();
            Log.v("Build", uri.build().toString());
            Log.v("Uri", uri.toString());

            URL imageUrl = new URL("http://" + "....com" + url);
            Log.v("URL 3", imageUrl.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            //Log.v("bitmap 6", bitmap.toString());
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            Log.v("bitmap 7", bitmap.toString());
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {

        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                // return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                Log.v("URL 2", photoToLoad.url.toString());
                Log.v("Bitmap  bmp", bmp.toString());
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);

                //if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                //return;
                //BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                //handler.post(bd);
                //Log.v("bd", bd.toString());

            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /* boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
         String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
         if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
             return true;
         return false;
     }
   */
             class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            Log.v("bitmap b", b.toString());
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            // if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
            //Log.v("BITMAP", bitmap.toString());
            // return;
            //}
            Log.v("BITMAP", bitmap.toString());
            if (bitmap != null) {
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Log.v("bitmap 2", bitmap.toString());
            } else {
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }
    }


    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}

public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

    //Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10, 1.5f, true));

    //Current allocated size
    private long size = 0;

    //Max memory in bytes
    private long limit = 1000000;

    public MemoryCache() {
        //Use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit) {
        limit = new_limit;
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id) {
        try {
            if (!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            return cache.get(id);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            if (cache.containsKey(id))
                size -= getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size += getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size=" + size + " length=" + cache.size());
        if (size > limit) {

            //Least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter = cache.entrySet().iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Bitmap> entry = iter.next();
                size -= getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if (size <= limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size " + cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try {
            cache.clear();
            size = 0;
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap == null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}

public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context) {

        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir = new File(
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "");
        else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url) {
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear() {
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        if (files == null)
            return;
        for (File f : files)
            f.delete();
    }

}

public static class Utils {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        final int buffer_size = 1024;
        try {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
            for (; ; ) {
                int count = is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                if (count == -1)
                    break;
                os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}

     /* public class SingleItemView extends Activity {

    String carimg;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        //Get the result of CarImageLink
        carimg = i.getStringExtra("CarImageLink");
        Log.v("carimg", i.getStringExtra("CarImageLink").toString());

        int loader = R.drawable.temp_img;
        int stub_id = loader;
        //Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
        ImageView img_car = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.car_img);
        Log.v("Imageview img_car", img_car.toString());

        //Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        //Passes carimg images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(carimg, stub_id, img_car);
    }
   }*/
 }
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response! I received this error: 'put(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' in 'java.util.HashMap' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>)' Any suggestions, please?

Comment: resultp.put(TAG_IMG, data.get(position)); The second argument is said to be wrong that a string is needed and not a hashmap value.

Comment: yeah the problem is that data is an arraylist of hashmaps. So what is happening here that the code is casting from hashmap to string.

Comment: I am trying to get the position in the hashmap where an image is being stored to display that said image in gridView.

Comment: Try this : data.get(position).get("CarImageLink") instead of data.get(position)

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. The same errors as listed above are occurring. If you have any other suggestions, they are much appreciated since I am stumped even after debugging. Thank you.

Comment: I know that this is a bit of trouble but I also need to see the error please.

Comment: Please check : resultp.put(TAG_IMG,data.get(position).get("CarImageLink))";
            carimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_img);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(TAG_IMG), carimg);

Comment: I am sorry if I am burdening you. The same errors I stated above still apply after looking at those three lines of code.  at com.example.justin.myapplication.JSONImageViewer$ImageLoader.DisplayImage(JSONImageViewer.java:292) applies to       imageView.setImageResource(stub_id); and at com.example.justin.myapplication.JSONImageViewer$ListViewAdapter.getView(JSONImageViewer.java:231) applies to  imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(TAG_IMG), carimg);

Comment: Can you update the question to show the xml or please send it over this email : miriaian.itani1@gmail.com.

Comment: Hello. I updated with xml files and two new null pointer exceptions after much research, debugging and logging. Any suggestions, madam, are appreciated. Thank you.